# MVC: "The incoming request does not match any route." - with a default request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am getting this error only SOMETIMES (apparently randomly, though I know there's really no such thing in computers).

I'm working on an MVC (release 1) site in VS 2008. The machine is running Windows 7 with IIS 7, but this instance is running under the Webserver built into VS (Cassini?). When I do an F5 to start running it, I will sometimes get an exception trap at the 4th line of the Page_Load method of Default.aspx.cs:

```
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

The exception method is:
The incoming request does not match any route.

Examining the `HttpContext.Current.Request` object shows a path of "/", and a rawUrl of "/Default.aspx?" - i.e, your normal empty request to a site.

The MapRoutes routine is pretty much standard except for a couple of IgnoreRoutes lines (ignore "pics/{*imgfile}", and ignore "{*favicon}").  The Application_Start routine has configuration for a StructureMap, and a call to SetControllerFactory before the call to RegisterRoutes, but it otherwise standard.

Usually, if I restart VS, the problem goes away.  (And almost always if I restart the machine).

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: I've gathered some more input and figured out the cirumstances under which this occurs (it's not random after all). But I still don't get the connection.

If I attempt to Debug the program in VS and the SQL server is not running on my machine, the program throws an exception in StructureMap, which is understandable and to be expected. If I stop the Debugger, start the SQL server, and re-run the program, that's when these errors occur.  

I still don't get the connection, but at least I know what to do to keep it from happening (close VS, start the SQL server, and restart).

Comment: Dave - Did you ever figure out what was causing this? I'm having the exact same thing happen to me. I set a breakpoint in Global.asax:Application_Start() - the breakpoint is not being hit.

Answer (score 1):

Set a default Page.  F5 in asp.net will launch to whatever page is selected.  However since in MVC, your View may or may not have an associated controller function, it can be trying to call an action that doesn't exist.  Open up your project properties and set the debug start page to your site home controller action.

Comment: Russell,
Thanks for taking the time to respond.

There is a default page set, and it is the standard code-behind for that default page (Default.aspx.cs) that is running and throwing the exception.  There is a start project set, and, all the actions exist, particularly the default action (controller=home, action=index).  Since this runs most of the time and only fails intermittentently, it's difficult to see how that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my poor english ...

I had this problem too! Misteriously the method Application_Start that call the routes disappeared in the Global.asax!!

vb.net:

```
Sub Application_Start()
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

put this method in global.asax if it doesn't exist